# Memory error calling Python from Julia

Tags: python, xml, julia

I want to use the Python package "Beautiful Soup" but from Julia. When I try to use the Julia package PyCall to get there I get an error.

The examples on https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl/ all work for me (with the exception of `plt.plot`)

I do the following:

```
ENV["PYTHON"]="C:\\Users\\AName\\Anaconda2\\python.exe"
Pkg.build("PyCall")

using PyCall
@pyimport bs4 #need BeautifulSoup
markup=open("c:\\work\\theImData.xml","r")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(PyTextIO(markup),"lxml")
```

And receive the following response:

```
julia> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(PyTextIO(markup),"lxml")
ERROR: PyError (:PyObject_Call) <type 'exceptions.MemoryError'>
MemoryError('Julia exception: OutOfMemoryError()',)
  File "C:\Users\AName\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 191, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
  File "PyCall.jl", line 1, in <lambda>

 in pyerr_check at C:\Users\AName\.julia\v0.5\PyCall\src\exception.jl:56 [inlined]
 in pyerr_check at C:\Users\AName\.julia\v0.5\PyCall\src\exception.jl:61 [inlined]
 in macro expansion at C:\Users\AName\.julia\v0.5\PyCall\src\exception.jl:81 [inlined]
 in #_pycall#62(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::PyCall.PyObject, ::PyCall.PyObject, ::Vararg{Any,N}) at C:\Users\AName\.julia\v0
.5\PyCall\src\PyCall.jl:546
 in _pycall(::PyCall.PyObject, ::PyCall.PyObject, ::Vararg{Any,N}) at C:\Users\AName\.julia\v0.5\PyCall\src\PyCall.jl:534
 in #pycall#66(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::PyCall.PyObject, ::Type{PyCall.PyAny}, ::PyCall.PyObject, ::Vararg{Any,N}) at C:\Users\B
jornPersson\.julia\v0.5\PyCall\src\PyCall.jl:568
 in pycall(::PyCall.PyObject, ::Type{PyCall.PyAny}, ::PyCall.PyObject, ::Vararg{Any,N}) at C:\Users\AName\.julia\v0.5\PyCall\s
rc\PyCall.jl:568
 in #call#67(::Array{Any,1}, ::PyCall.PyObject, ::PyCall.PyObject, ::Vararg{Any,N}) at C:\Users\AName\.julia\v0.5\PyCall\src\P
yCall.jl:571
 in (::PyCall.PyObject)(::PyCall.PyObject, ::Vararg{Any,N}) at C:\Users\AName\.julia\v0.5\PyCall\src\PyCall.jl:571
```

In order to make sure the `.xml` is small I test with an `.xml` containing only the following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FacitData>
 <DirectoryData directory="0028">
  <Image fileName="image_0000911.png" />
 </DirectoryData>
</FacitData>
```

Am I calling PyCall correctly?